# Plus 1 hour to timedatestamp

Tags: php

I have a function that converts long-date times to human readable format. However i need to add an hour to those times. Below is what i tired but it does not work. My original function is found below that, which does work but does not add the additional 1 hour to the time.

Not working adding an additional hour function

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    function convertDateTime($datestamp) {
   $dt = new DateTime("@$datestamp");
   $newdate= $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

   return $newdate("+1 hour");
}
```

Working function that does not add hour to the output

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    function convertDateTime($datestamp) {
   $dt = new DateTime("@$datestamp");
   $newdate= $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

   return $newdate;
```

Comment: `$dt = new DateTime("@" . ($datestamp+3600));` ?! And then use your working code with this new code line

Comment: $new_datetime = date( 'Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime( '+3 hours',  $timestamp ) );


Where $timestamp is your current timestamp in which you want to add 1 hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    function convertDateTime($datestamp) {
    return  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datestamp+3600);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateInterval and add the specific amount of hours:

```
$date_ = new DateTime();
$date_->add(new DateInterval('P4H'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Go to https://packagist.org.

Search for `date`.

A well-liked package seems to be: [nestbot/carbon](https://packagist.org/packages/nesbot/carbon).

```
 composer require nesbot/carbon
```

Use it:

```
 $dt = new Carbon("@$datestamp");
 $dt->addHour(1);
 $formattedString = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```